# UIView handle only double tap

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I want my view to handle only double tap gestures. The rest of the gestures should be forwarded to its superview. How could this be achieved?
I tried the `pointsInside` override trick but it forwards all the touches.

**Edit:**

Also the superview may or may not decide to handle the touches (it might decide to forward them to other views).
Actually what I am trying to achieve is to have a `UIWindow` over the initial one that reacts only to double tap, the rest of the touches should pass through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your double tap gesture recognizer to the super view, then in the gesture recognizer's delegate implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and return true only if it's within the frame of your view. This way you can set `userInteractionEnabled` to false on your view and everything will work. The view will be transparent to touches, except double taps. No need for any hitTest or pointInside overrides.

Comment: Your answer does indeed answer my question. However, I oversimplified it a bit at first. Now I added some more context.

Comment: This same idea can work. Set `userInteractionEnabled` to false on your `UIWindow` and add the gesture recognizer to the window beneath it.

Comment: I'll try that and if it works I'll accept your answer. Not sure if it's gonna work because there are many subviews in the window beneath that might get the touch.